# Joining bronze gear to bronze shaft

Tags: gears, machining

I'd like to build a scale model catapult, and I'm building a tensioning/ratchet system similar to what is shown in this video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yi4p8ZR4n28

The ratchet gear in the video has a square keyway and the rotating bar is cut square as well, giving a high strength joint.

Unfortunately I don't have a mill or a lathe, so mechanically fastening my gear to my shaft would be difficult. I'm wondering if a bronze-on-bronze shrink fit would be strong enough to hold the torsion force. Or whether a brazed joint would be enough. Given that this is a scale model using torsion ropes, I don't really know how much force that would be either.

Comment: nothing stopping you from using both interference and a key

Comment: A close fit with high-strength loctite [(example)](https://www.henkel-adhesives.com/us/en/product/retaining-compounds/loctite_609.html) is surprisingly strong -  if it's keyed it might be good enough

Answer (score 2):

A shrink fit is possible, but do you have the mill or lathe to make the appropriate dimensions and then sufficient heating and/or cooling?

Liquid nitrogen is a possibility, but a household freezer is about -18 deg C and a household oven about 280 deg C, which means a delta T of 300.

Comment: Dry ice may be available in some grocery stores. A keyway is a poor method to transmit torque , shrink fit is preferred .  Hot water is convenient to expand one member.

Comment: @blacksmith37 I did not mention a keyway.

Comment: kudos on needing to machine an interference fit

Comment: The OP specifically said they don’t have a mill or lathe.

Answer (score 2):

As you don't have a mill or a lathe, I don't see much options here. Brazing is a very strong joint if done properly (nearly as good as welding).

You could also drill, tools permitting, a round keyway or keyways.